# Creating and accessing array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I'm having trouble figuring out how to access data in an array of objects. I've spent hours trying to find some example of this, but all I find is you must reference arrays by an index number, which doesn't seem efficient.

For example, I have a table of animals and the number of legs on that animal. How do I access the value (number of legs) for that animal based on the name of the animal. If I pass "human" to a function I want to be able to return "2".

Is this concept called something I'm not yet familiar with yet? Is it just not possible to use a "key" to access data in an array? Do I really have to use a loop to search through the entire array to fine the right entry if I don't know the index number?

What is the simplest way to do this?

```
let animalsLegs = [{animal: "human", legs: 2},
                   {animal: "horse", legs: 4},
                   {animal: "fish", legs: 0}]

function findLegs(animalToFind) {
  return animalLegs[animalToFind];
}

console.log(findLegs("human"));
```

I would expect an output of `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an object instead of an array:

```js
const animalLegsByAnimalName = {
  human: 2,
  horse: 4,
  fish: 0
};
function findLegs(animalToFind) {
  return animalLegsByAnimalName[animalToFind];
}
console.log(findLegs("human"));
```

If you want to *keep* using the array, but also use an object for quick, easy lookup, just `reduce` the initial array into the above object first:

```js
const animalsLegs = [{animal: "human", legs: 2},
                   {animal: "horse", legs: 4},
                   {animal: "fish", legs: 0}];
const animalLegsByAnimalName = animalsLegs.reduce((a, { animal, legs }) => {
  a[animal] = legs;
  return a;
}, {});

function findLegs(animalToFind) {
  return animalLegsByAnimalName[animalToFind];
}
console.log(findLegs("human"));
```

If the object in the array is more complicated than that, and you (for example) want access to additional properties, you can have the object's values be the object in the array, instead of just the value of the `leg` property:

```js
const animalsLegs = [{animal: "human", legs: 2},
                   {animal: "horse", legs: 4},
                   {animal: "fish", legs: 0}];
const animalLegsByAnimalName = animalsLegs.reduce((a, animalObj) => {
  a[animalObj.animal] = animalObj;
  return a;
}, {});

function findLegs(animalToFind) {
  const foundAnimal = animalLegsByAnimalName[animalToFind];
  if (!foundAnimal) {
    return 'No animal found with that name!';
  }
  return foundAnimal.legs;
}
console.log(findLegs("human"));
```

Comment: The object example is initially what I had tried. Codepen really didn't like something I was doing. That led to me trying to do more complex things. Thx for all of these solutions, I will dig into each of these to really understanding what is going on. Really appreciate your response!!!

Comment: I can't find any reference or docs that indicate what the extra `{}` is for on line 7. Having a hard time wrapping my head around arrow functions because it seems there are dozens of ways to use them and very documentation on all the ways.

Comment: The `{}` isn't inside the arrow function (and since `this` isn't involved, the arrow function is equivalent to a standard `function`) - the `{}` is the second parameter passed to `reduce`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce , whose second parameter is the initial value for the accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the Array data structure:

```
function findLegs(animalToFind) {
  const animal = animalsLegs.find(animal => animal.name === animalToFind);

  return animal.legs;
}
```

PS: An array data structure is more inefficient than an object, it will take O(n) to find an item, while an object is like a hash table, you can find values in O(1). You can read more about Big O notation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: I can't wrap my brain around what `animal => animal.name === animalToFind` is doing. What is `animal` doing in this pieces of code? is that what is being returned to `const animal`? What is this logic called?

Answer (score 1):

I think an array is best for this kind of data, you simply have to write a small function to retrieve what you want.

```js
const animals = [
  { animal: "human",  legs: 2 },
  { animal: "horse",  legs: 4 },
  { animal: "fish",   legs: 0 }
]

function getAnimalByName(name) {
  return animals.reduce((a, b) => b.animal !== name ? a : b, null)
}

// Human?!
console.log(getAnimalByName('fish'))
```

Comment: I read about the reduce function at http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html but couldn't for the life of me figure out what I had read and what it was called! Thanks! Really appreciate the response!

Comment: I think I also noticed `console.log(getAnimalByName('human').legs)` returns the legs where `console.log(getAnimalByName('fish'))`returns the object. Cool to see both.